# How to map list of attributes to column-based schema with condition in BizTalk?

Tags: schema, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have two schema one is for input xml file and second is for database table.

Please look below for source data of above schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl'?> 
<List>
 <Classification domain="Type">deviceSku</Classification>
 <Classification domain="Color">(PRODUCT)RED</Classification>
 <Classification domain="ColorCode">#D82E2E</Classification>
 <Classification domain="OS">Apple iOS</Classification>
 <Classification domain="ChargeType">One Time Charge</Classification>
 <Classification domain="Capacity">128GB</Classification>
</List>
```

Above file is input xml file which is in list form.

Please look below for table creation scripts which is output, and it is based on column format.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cata_class](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    [classification_type] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [classification_color] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [classification_colorCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [classification_os] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [classification_chargetype] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [classification_capacity] [varchar](100) NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) 
GO
```

[image]

As per above SS. I want to add classification value based on condition of domain in destination schema so which functiod is better option and how to use that function?

Please look below for input schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="List">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Classification">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="domain" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Please look below for output schema:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Types/Tables/dbo" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Types/Tables/dbo" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <fileNameHint xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/servicemodel/adapters/metadata/xsd">Table.dbo</fileNameHint>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:complexType name="cata_class">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ID" nillable="true" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="classification_type" nillable="true">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="100" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="classification_color" nillable="true">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="100" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="classification_colorCode" nillable="true">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="50" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="classification_os" nillable="true">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="100" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="classification_chargetype" nillable="true">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="100" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="classification_capacity" nillable="true">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="100" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="cata_class" nillable="true" type="ns3:cata_class" />
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfcata_class">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="cata_class" type="ns3:cata_class" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ArrayOfcata_class" nillable="true" type="ns3:ArrayOfcata_class" />
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Please provide an input schema, a output schema, a sample XML file, and what you have tried so far.   Hint.  You probably want a looping functoid, a equal functoid and a value mapping functoid

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Please look edits you will have both schema SS and for sample XML file please prefer first SS of question.

Comment: The actual schemas as text please, formatted as code blocks with ``` around them, not screenshots.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I replace all ss with code file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use Equal and Value mapping (flattering) function as per below SS:

[image]

On equal functiod we need to pass domain to check condition as below:

[image]

and in value mapping (flattering) functiod we need to pass equal functiod value as first input and classification node as second input and map it to destination schema node.